# Misaligned logo on SE 404 page

Tags: bug, design, 404-not-found

Today, I typed `augur.stackexchange.com` wrongly and landed in a 404 page. However, the logo is weird and misaligned. I tried a few more times with a different url name and the result is the same.
[image: misaligned]

OS: macOS High Sierra, browser: Chrome, Safari 
OS: iOS, browser: Safari 
OS: Windows 10, browser: Chrome, Firefox, Edge

Comment: *I typed augur wrongly* ...To get from augur to  asdadf I more suspect cat on keyboard ...

Comment: No repro in Chrome, IE 11, and Edge.

Comment: No repro on Firefox either. Please add your browser and OS.

Comment: @rene This screenshot was from the second time that I tested

Comment: @KodosJohnson I added the information. I also just reproduced on mobile.

Comment: no repro in chrome mac sierra https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuBJf.png

Comment: Strangely enough I don't get that logo anywhere, nor didn't it load: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2ccM.png, you do get the Panda, right?

Comment: I reproduced the problem in Chrome on my macbook. OS: High Sierra 10.13.2. Chrome version: 64.0.3282.186

Comment: @rene I get the panda... Also, I'm on High Sierra, probably the problem

Comment: It's probably caused by this css ruleset: `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, not all{header h1{background:transparent url('img/se-logo@2x.png?v=5663d7dbb7ab') no-repeat left top;background-size:223px 52px}}`. Looks like retina display devices would be targeted.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it on Windows 10 in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG9q9.jpg), [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOu9f.jpg) and [Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oILne.jpg).

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome 64 Android. I also think this may be a duplicate question; ISTR seeing it before, but I can't find it right now...